# Freemarker: keep trailing zeroes in BigDecimal

Tags: java, freemarker

I'd like to copy a `BigDecimal` value with an arbitrary number of traling zeroes into a Freemarker template as-is (e.g., if calling `value.toString()` in Java results in `123.0000`, I want to see exactly `123.0000` inserted into template).

However, using the built-ins (like `?string`) or just `${valueWithZeroes}` always seems to strip trailing zeroes away. Using `?string[...]` is out of the question as the exact number of trailing zeroes is unknown. AFAIK, there's a way to call `BigDecimal`'s own `toString` method from Freemarker template using `?api` - however, the docs seem to disourage doing this. So I wonder if there's any other way to achieve that using Freemarker itself, without falling back to Java methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `java.text.DecimalFormat` can't do that, and therefore FreeMarker can't do that out of the box. But, you can define your own `CustomNumberFormatFactory`, and do whatever is possible in Java. See example for that here: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_custom_formats.html.
So you do something like `HexTemplateNumberFormatFactory` there, and you can also set your custom number format as the default number format (by setting the `number_format` to `"@hex"` in the example).

Note that if you are just using `BigDecimal.toString` as is, the formatting won't consider the `Locale`. So your decimal separator will be wrong in some languages.